# How can i add linked data source to website?

Tags: list-view, lookup-column, joined-view

I got two lists. And I want to join , merge them and select the same IDs.But i don't want to do this on Sharepoint Designer. I only use browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can export them to excel if its one time, there is no OOB Webparts which you can achieve above.